# Conversão de parâmetros com Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony-2

Alguém sabe alguma maneira elegante de converter uma parâmetro no symfony2 eu sei que existe o [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) do Symfony2 porém não utilizo annotations. Alguma alternativa ?

Comment: Até onde eu sei, o ParamConverter é a única maneira para se converter parâmetros em objetos. Pessoalmente, gosto muito de usar annotations pois coloco praticamente todas as informações referentes a uma determinada *action* nas annotations.

Comment: Bom annotations no meu caso mata todas as heranças de controladores que eu tenho, e gera um alto nível de acoplamento entre configurações e classes o que é horrível para o reaproveitamento de classes já que ela está amarrada a uma configuração feita por annotation. Cada caso é um caso, no meu annotations não me atendem. Estou pensando em fazer um bundle para isso já que não encontro nada =S

Comment: Resolvi, vou adicionar uma resposta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é necessário usar annotations para o `ParamConverter`, ao contrário do que eu havia dito antes.

Primeiro você precisa criar uma classe que implemente a interface `ParamConverterInterface`, conforme o código abaixo:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Request\ParamConverter;

use Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Teste;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TesteParamConverter implements ParamConverterInterface
{
    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        $param = $configuration->getName();
        $request->attributes->set($param, new Teste());

        return true;
    }

    public function supports(ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        return ("Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Teste" === $configuration->getClass());
    }
}
```

Depois, registre esse `ParamConverter` nos serviços da sua aplicação com a tag `request.param_converter`:

```
parameters:
    acme.request.param_converter.teste_param_converter.class: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Request\ParamConverter\TesteParamConverter

services:
    acme.request.param_converter.teste:
        class: %acme.request.param_converter.teste_param_converter.class%
        tags:
            - { name: request.param_converter }
```

Por fim, você precisa definir o que vai receber na *action* por meio do seu `ParamConverter`. No meu caso eu criei uma entidade `Teste` só para o propósito da resposta, mesmo:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity;

class Teste
{
}
```

Espero ter ajudado! :)

Comment: Genial, ajudou de mais, sem palavras